# Cascading Drop Down Validation using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am having two Cascading Drop Downs. Drop Down 1 having values A,B,C. If A is selected It populates values 1,2,3 in Drop Down 2. If B is selected It populates values 6,7,8.

Requirement: I want to validate Cascading Drop Downs in such a way that if A is selected in Drop Down 1 and 1 is selected in Drop Down 2. It should allow for the first time. I can add a new row by clicking the add button . Again when I select A in Drop Down 1 and 1 in Drop Down 2. It should not allow at the time of submit/save click. Kindly provide a jQuery script to validate this. Thanks in advance.

function ValidationCascadingDD() {
        debugger;

```
    $('select[id^="ddlApplicableGroup_infrastructure"]').each(
      //start outerloop against each element
      function (index, element) {
          //find all the items again
          $('select[id^="ddlProfileName_infrastructure"]').each(
            //start inner loop on each item
            function (indexInner, elementInner) {
                debugger;
                if (index != indexInner) {
                    //compare the items here as they are not the same index numbers so are different elements
                    //there are different ways to compare, but you could use jquery again for this
                    //and use the element and elementInner to access each of them.
                    if ($(element).val() == $(elementInner).val())

                        alert("2 dd have the same value:" + element.id + ":" + elementInner.id);
                }
            }
         );
      }
    );


}
```

Comment: What you have tried ? Show your code..

Comment: $('select[id^="ddlApplicableGroup_infrastructure"]').each(
function (index, element) {
$('select[id^="ddlProfileName_infrastructure"]').each(
 function (indexInner, elementInner) {
if (index != indexInner) {
if ($(element).val() == $(elementInner).val())
 alert("2 dd have the same value:" + element.id + ":" + elementInner.id);
} } );} );

Comment: @Napster I have code to validate for drop down with same values. But I want code snippet to validate cascading drop down.